# How to use media query to change cell padding at specific resolution?

Tags: css, email, responsive-design, media-queries, html-email

When viewed in desktop view (> 480px) I need a particular `<td>` to have a left-padding of 9px but, when the resolution drops below 480px, I need this left-padding to increase to 18px.

Currently, my padding definition is inline:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  td[class=paddingControl]{
   padding-left:18px !important;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <td style="padding-top:0px; padding-left:9px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;" class="paddingControl">
    Data Here
  </td>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.
Any ideas?

Many Thanks!

Comment: what email client is it not working in? have you run it through Litmus or Email on Acid?

Comment: Hi @Gortonington; I just ran this in Litmus and it works perfectly. I think the lesson for me is: the browser lies when it comes to responsive email design! (I was testing in Chrome only), not as an actual email! My apologies.

Comment: yeah there are so many differences between email client preprocessors and different browser processors that it is impossible to judge if it works on a single preview or test.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having run this code in an email testing application; I realized it worked perfectly. Lesson learnt: test in email format; not just within the browser.

As was mentioned by Gortonington, "there are so many differences between email client preprocessors and different browser processors that it is impossible to judge if it works on a single preview or test".